# Excel VBA: How to disable external references to a veryhidden tab?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a pw-protected Excel file to send to an end-user. There are veryhidden tabs in the workbook.

I want to prevent said end-user from just opening a new workbook, creating a cell reference to one of the veryhidden tabs assuming they can guess those tab names (generic names (e.g. "Inputs")) and recreating the file from there.

Is there a way to do this in VBA?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily crack password protected Excel spreadsheets so whatever you do people will still be able to see.

I tried and referenced data in another password protected spreadsheet using linked workbooks, then I changed the Sheet and it didn't change the data source. So by default it doesn't let you "guess" or pick a Hidden or VeryHidden sheet.

However when Copy/Paste Special -> Paste Link then nothing I know of can stop people changing the reference address.

```
=[Spreadsheet.xlsm]Sheet3!B2
```

Unless in the Workbook_Change event you mandate certain keywords can't be used as cell references.

In a WorkSheet's code behind:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)    
  If InStr(1, Range(Target.Address).Value, "reserved", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    Range(Target.Address).Value = Replace(Range(Target.Address).Value, "reserved", "")
    Call MsgBox("Please don't use ""reserved"" keywords.", vbInformation)
  End If    
End Sub
```

Again, people would see this in the VBA code and you can't obfuscate it. The answer is no.

Comment: Thank you. I know pw-protection is not strong, but need it for this purpose. Can you explain what you mean here: "Unless in the Workbook_Change event you mandate certain keywords can't be used as cell references". If there's a way to prevent a keyword e.g. "Spreadsheet!" being used as a cell reference, then I can just code that in VBA and then pw-protect the module, no?

Comment: @Abhi see update example. I don't recommend this, but it will work for *most* users who don't know or use VBA.

Comment: This only appears to work within the protected worksheet itself, doesn't prevent calling a cell reference from another workbook to the subject worksheet. But thank you for the effort anyway sir.

Comment: If you need to lock it down please don't rely on Password Protection and Hidden sheets, instead securely download the secret data from the VBA or consider making the Excel spreadsheet a website. Good luck 